# Java/Scala implementations of IND-CCA2 secure asymmetric ciphers?

Tags: encryption, java

I am currently looking into asymmetric (not hybrid!) encryption for a software project. Being a good boy, of course I'm not going to roll my own implementation, but looking for a library to provide me with the desired functionality.

Requirement for the encryption is IND-CCA2 as well as it being available on the JVM (for usage with Scala).

Now there is a default implementation of RSA (OAEPWithSHA-xAndMGF1Padding), provided in the [JCE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJCEProvider) which would fulfill these requirements, but my question is whether there are other libraries out there which would

- provide a compatible implementation

or

- whether there is another algorithm which would fulfill my main requirements (asymmetric, IND-CCA2 and JVM)?

Comment: Do you only encrypt short messages (up to 200ish bytes)? And why don't you like hybrid encryption?

Comment: I have nothing against hybrid encryption; in fact I am already using it in this particular software. Without going into too much detail, It's a necessity, that only the destination party be able to retrieve the plaintext, using its private key, while everybody is able to send it messages.
And yes, only short messages will get encrypted. ~256Bytes upper limit is my intended ballpark. But this might change.

Comment: What happens when the scope of your software project changes and all of a sudden you have to encrypt long messages? Don't say that won't happen, it will :) Also, is there any specific reason not to use the crypto provider supplied by Sun? There is always [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).

Comment: I agree with mikeazo. There will be libraries of course, but as long as you don't define why the OAEP implementation of the Oracle provider isn't sufficient, it will be hard to recommend any of them. What do you mean with compatible - are you looking for code compatibility or binary compatibility of the output - i.e. another OAEP implementation?

Comment: I'm not worried about changing specs or (non-)usability of Sun's crypto provider or even whether the provided threat-model is applicable; I am simply interested in usable alternative algorithms/implementations like ElGamal or Cramer-Shoup, of which I have found neither. Possibly along with performance/security properties. OR other open libraries, providing an alternative (superior?) implementation of RSA-OAEP.